# access the values every where in multiple components in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i have to use the user object coming from db in every component , for that i have choose ionic-storage to store user and even i can access any where in my component. but i got an issue when using ngOnChanges() in my component. the ngOnChanges is triggered before my constructor got initialized, in my constructor i have a logic to get the user from localStorage.

in ngOnChanges() method i checking if user exits assigning some value. my condition fails every time because getting user logic is defined in constructor.

### child Component

```
     @Component({
      selector: 'my-fav-icon',
      templateUrl:``<ion-icon name="ios-heart-outline"  *ngIf="IsLike" (click)="onAddToFavorite()"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="ios-heart" *ngIf="!IsLike" (click)="onAddToFavorite()"></ion-icon>
`,
       })
         import { Component,Input,OnChanges,DoCheck} from '@angular/core';
            import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

            export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
             constructor(public storage:Storage) {
             this.storage.get('authentication').then((userResp) => {
               this.user = userResp
                console.log('category-video.ts -->Name has been set'+JSON.stringify(userResp));   //printed second
              });

              }


          IsLike:String
            @Input() 
            singleItem : any;

            ngOnChanges(changes){
                console.log('on-ng-changes is called');//printed first
                if(this.user){ 
                  if(this.user.favorites.indexOf(changes.currentValue.videoId) == -1){
                      this.IsLike =true;  
                    }else{
                    this.IsLike =false;
                    }
                }else{
                    this.IsLike =true;
                }


        }

            }
```

### parent component

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'page-categories',
  templateUrl: 'categories.html',
})
 export class ParentComponent{

}
```

### categories.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of cats">
<h1>My parent class component</h1>
<ion-col text-right>
  <my-favorite-icon [singleItem]="item" ></my-favorite-icon>
 </ion-col>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your service call out of the constructor and use ngOnInit or ionViewDidLoad. You should do that anyway, but I could not get ngOnChanges to work with any ionic components yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lifecycle` events specified for ionic, like `ionViewDidEnter`, `ionViewWillEnter` etc. which enables you to get the content before constructor or after constructor call according to your need.

It will be better if you choose these lifecycle events rather than `*ngOnChanges*`, so that you could get the user credentials.

**EDIT**

Also look into `ionChange`, i don't have used it before, so please have a look.